# How to select and calculate time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table like this:

[image]

what I want to do is do calculation "jam" between 08:31:31 and 08:30:46 where "aksi_ID" 4 and 9 and "nomor_antrian" 2 and 1. and the result in minute.

I know there are similar question, but I think its difference condition. So how to solve query?

Comment: what you tried till now

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: Please include more information, what you mean by idle time, and what you mean by `calculate the time in a sign`?

Comment: @RaymondTey yes I agree with you. The line `how to calculate the time in a sign in the picture to get idle time` is not understandable

Comment: how to select and calculate jam 08:31:31 with jam 08:30:46 ? the result will be idle time for my program. sorry for my bad english

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220863/mysql-query-to-get-time-difference I made a simple question for this post. hope you guys can solve this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
WITH tab AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aksi_id ORDER BY jam) AS rowNo, t1.* FROM test_table t1)

SELECT t1.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t2.jam, t1.jam) AS diff FROM tab t1
  LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t2.aksi_id = t1.aksi_id AND t2.rowNo = t1.rowNo - 1;
```

It works for MariaDB, I'm not sure about mysql. And I ignored *nomor_antrian*, you have to implement where you need it.

Comment: thank you for your helping but its still not work for me. I made a simple quetion on this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220863/mysql-query-to-get-time-difference hope anyone can solve